# Copy several files

Tags: files, gnome-terminal, cp

I have a list of files, and I want to generate several copies of them. The copies should be numbered.

For example, I have the files:

```
fileA, fileB, ..., fileC
```

The first copy should generate the files

```
fileA1, fileB1, ..., fileC1
```

the second copy, the files

```
fileA2, fileB2, ..., fileC2
```

and so on, until a specific number of copies is reached.

What commands can I use to accomplish this from the terminal?

Comment: Could you confirm that none of the original file names end with a number? Do you want the copies in the same directory or in a different one? If you interrupted a copy half way through and you end up with files fileA, fileA1, fileA2, fileB, fileB1, fileC, fileC1 what would you expect the next copy to do?

Comment: @sмurf The original file names can end in numbers. The copies can end in the same directory or in a different one; I am looking for a generic solution in this aspect. If I interrupt a copy half way, the next copy should behave as defined, that is, there is no way to recognize that the files it sees now have been copied before.

Comment: If the original files can end in numbers and the copies can be in the same directory then you have no reliable way of knowing whether fileA1 is an original (and should be copied) or a copy (and should not be copied). The only way around this is to have a "database" with the original filenames stored somewhere else and another "database" with the last number used. This is not a simple solution and will be sensitive to corruption of both databases. Good luck with that.

Comment: I wonder why you need such many copies of the same files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this GNU  `find` command,

```
find . -type f -exec cp {} {}1 \; -exec cp {} {}2 \;
```

- Searches for files inside the current directory and perform the operation mentioned in `-exec` on the files founded.
- `-exec cp {} {}1 \;` --> First copy operation is done by this command in which original files are copied to the same directory itself where the names in the duplicate files are ended with 1.
- `-exec cp {} {}2 \;` --> Second copy operation is done by this command in which original files are copied to the same directory where the names in the duplicate files are ended with 2.